# java 7 upgrade and hibernate annotation processor error

Tags: migration, java-7, hibernate-annotations

I am getting the following warning, which seems to be triggering a subsequent warning and an error. I have been googling like mad, though have not found anything that makes it clear what it is I should do to resolve this. This issue occurs when I execute an Ant build. I am trying to migrate our project to Java 7. I have changed all the source='1.6' and target="1.6" to 1.7.

I did find this related article: [Forward compatible Java 6 annotation processor and SupportedSourceVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185331/forward-compatible-java-6-annotation-processor-and-supportedsourceversion)

It seems to indicate that I should build the Hibernate annotation processor jar myself, compiling it with with 1.7. It does not seem I should be required to do so. The latest version of the class in question (in hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-5.0.1.Final.jar) has been compiled with 1.6. Since the code in said class refers to SourceVersion.latestSupported(), and the 1.6 of that returns only RELEASE_6, there does not seem to be a generally available solution.

Here is the warning:

```
[javac] warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.hibernate.validator.ap.ConstraintValidationProcessor' less than -source '1.7'
```

And, here are the subsequent warnings/error.

```
[javac] warning: No processor claimed any of these annotations: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext,javax.persistence.Column,org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore,javax.persistence.Id,org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn,com.trgr.cobalt.infrastructure.datasource.Bucketed,org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize,javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn,com.trgr.cobalt.dataroom.authorization.secure.Secured,org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator,javax.annotation.Resource,com.trgr.cobalt.infrastructure.spring.domain.DomainField,org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect,javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue,com.trgr.cobalt.dataroom.datasource.config.core.CoreTransactionMandatory,org.springframework.stereotype.Repository,javax.persistence.GeneratedValue,com.trgr.cobalt.dataroom.datasource.config.core.CoreTransactional,org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade,javax.persistence.Table,javax.persistence.Enumerated,org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef,javax.persistence.OneToOne,com.trgr.cobalt.dataroom.datasource.config.core.CoreEntity,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional,com.trgr.cobalt.infrastructure.util.enums.EnumConversion,org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration,com.trgr.cobalt.infrastructure.spring.domain.UpdatedFields,com.trgr.cobalt.infrastructure.spring.documentation.SampleValue,org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean,org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty,javax.persistence.Basic,org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize,com.trgr.cobalt.infrastructure.spring.validation.Required,com.trgr.cobalt.dataroom.datasource.config.core.CoreTransactionNever,org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile,com.trgr.cobalt.infrastructure.spring.stereotype.Persistor,javax.persistence.Transient,com.trgr.cobalt.infrastructure.spring.validation.NotNull,javax.validation.constraints.Size,javax.persistence.Entity,javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn,org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize,org.springframework.stereotype.Service,org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value,javax.persistence.Inheritance
[javac] error: warnings found and -Werror specified
```

TIA!

Comment: This has something about suppressing these warnings and a warning why that may be a bad idea: http://code.google.com/p/immutablej/

Here's another similar (but not duplicate) question that might yield some insights: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185331/forward-compatible-java-6-annotation-processor-and-supportedsourceversion

Answer (score 0):

Annotation processors are annotated by this

```
 @SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_7)
```

apparently your hibernate annotation processor supports only RELEASE_6 you have to upgrade it version